# Performing calculations in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Contacts.ContactId,
    ROUND(SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice), 2) AS  Owed,
    SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate,
    SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn,
    Deductions.DeductionRate
FROM 
    dbo.LandingDetails
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LandingHeaders ON LandingDetails.LandingId = LandingHeaders.LandingId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Vessels ON LandingHeaders.VesselId = Vessels.VesselId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Contacts ON Vessels.OwnerId = Contacts.ContactId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SocietyMemberships ON Contacts.SocietyId = SocietyMemberships.SocietyId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Deductions ON Vessels.DeductionId = Deductions.DeductionId
WHERE 
    LandingHeaders.Posted = 0
GROUP BY 
    Contacts.ContactId,
    SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate,
    SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn,
    Deductions.DeductionRate
```

Which produces the following table as its output;

[image]

I need some advice as to how I can add one further column to the output table which for the sake of argument we'll call `TotalDeductions`.

If we take the first row of the table as an example Total deductions would be calculated by taking a percentage (from the DeductionRate column), in this case 1.5%,  of the  owed column.  If after removing that 1.5% from the total of the owed column and removing the sum in the WeeklyDeductionRate, in this case 10.0, one is left with a sum that is at least 110 then the WeeklyDeductionRate can be taken.  If however the sum were to be below 110 after the WeeklyDeductionRate were removed then it should not be removed.

I'm sure that this can be done in SQL, just not sure where to start.

NB Although in the table of returned data shown all of the Columns `WeeklyDeductionRate`, `FromMinimumReturn` and `DeductionRate` show the same figures they can vary, so 'hard coding' figures isn't an option.

Thanks

EDIT

The database platform is SQL Server (either 2012 or 2014). As an example of what I would really like to end up with , and again taking the first row as an example I'd like to have a result set that reads:

```
ContactId      Owed             TotalDeductions
    39         1609.390000           34.14
```

where total deductions is made up of 1609.39 * 1.5% which = 24.14  plus 10 as the total 34.14 when deducted from 1609.39 would leave a balance of at least 110.

Comment: Try adding

   `ROUND(SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate, 2) AS TotalDeductions`

into your `SELECT` clause to get your TotalDeductions column. Not entirely sure however about the conditional side of things though.

Comment: Can you provide an example result set that you are trying to get?

Comment: Added additional info as a edit to the question, thanks for taking the time to look and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding the following case expression to your select statement should do it:

```
CASE WHEN 
   SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) 
   - 
   SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate 
   > FromMinimumReturn 
THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
ELSE 0 END
AS TotalDeductions
```

However, this has a lot of repeating code (the Owed calculation), so I would wrap the original query in a common table expression and do it like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  <<<your original query here>>> -- I left it out to save space...
)

SELECT 
    ContactId,
    Owed,
    WeeklyDeductionRate,
    FromMinimumReturn,
    DeductionRate,
    CASE 
       WHEN Owed - (Owed * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn 
       THEN Owed * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
       ELSE 0 END
    AS TotalDeductions
FROM cte
```

This will return to calculated TotalDeductions if subtracting it from the Owed leaves a result over the FromMinimumReturn else it will return 0 for TotalDeductions.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks for demonstrating how this can be done.  I made one small change, substituting the 0 for Owed * DeductionRate  after the else statement (as the business rule states that the deduction rate will always be taken, its just the addition deduction of the weeklyDeductionRate that's conditional upon what the final figured of owed ends up being.

Comment: @DomSinclair Happy it worked; I figured you probably had some business rule that should be used so the 0 was mostly a placeholder :)