# Adding relatively complex business logic to a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've had some superb assistance from a fellow SO user over the last few days, whose knowledge of SQL is clearly way above mine.  Now I could do with some advice from those more knowledgeable than me once again.  This question essentially follows on from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229474/embedding-a-sql-case-statement-into-a-sql-query-that-is-using-for-xml).

I have adapted the original query to meet requirements such that it now looks like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate date = '2015-01-05',
        @endDate date = '2015-06-05',
        @tempDeduction decimal(10, 4) = NULL



SELECT (SELECT
    ContactId AS '@ContactId',
    VesselOwner AS '@Owner',
    Owed AS '@Owed',
    WeeklyDeductionRate AS '@WeeklyDeductionRate',
    FromMinimumReturn AS '@FromMinimumReturn',
    DeductionRate AS '@DeductionRate',
    TotalDeductions AS '@TotalDeductions',
    TotalToBeReturned AS '@TotalToBeReturned',
    InternalCommission AS '@InternalCommissionRate',
    InternalDeduction AS '@InternalDeductionRate',



    (SELECT DISTINCT
      ld1.ProductId AS '@ProductId',
      FORMAT(AVG(ld1.UnitPrice), 'N2') AS '@Cost',
      FORMAT(SUM(ld1.Quantity), 'N2') AS '@Quantity'

    FROM LandingDetails ld1
    INNER JOIN dbo.LandingHeaders lh1
      ON ld1.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
    WHERE Posted = 0
    AND lh1.VesselOwner = a.VesselOwner
    GROUP BY ld1.ProductId
    FOR xml PATH ('Products'), TYPE)

  FROM (SELECT
    Contacts.ContactId AS ContactId,
    LandingHeaders.VesselOwner AS VesselOwner,
    FORMAT(SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice), 'N2') AS Owed,
    SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate AS WeeklyDeductionRate,
    SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn AS FromMinimumReturn,
    Deductions.DeductionRate,
    Vessels.InternalCommission AS InternalCommissionRate,
    Vessels.InternalDeduction AS InternalDeductionRate,
    FORMAT(CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END, 'N2') AS TotalDeductions,


    --need to add some logic here I presume that utiles the sql below that is being used to calculate the total to be returned


    FORMAT(SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END), 'N2') AS TotalToBeReturned


  FROM dbo.LandingDetails
  INNER JOIN dbo.LandingHeaders
    ON LandingDetails.LandingId = LandingHeaders.LandingId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Vessels
    ON LandingHeaders.VesselId = Vessels.VesselId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts
    ON Vessels.OwnerId = Contacts.ContactId
  INNER JOIN dbo.SocietyMemberships
    ON Contacts.SocietyId = SocietyMemberships.SocietyId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Deductions
    ON Vessels.DeductionId = Deductions.DeductionId
  WHERE LandingHeaders.Posted = 0
  AND LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  GROUP BY ContactId,
           LandingHeaders.VesselOwner,
           SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate,
           SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn,
           Deductions.DeductionRate) a
  ORDER BY ContactId

  FOR xml PATH ('Owner'), TYPE)

FOR xml PATH ('PurchaseOrders'), TYPE
```

I had added logic so that the xml would also show the final amount ((once deductions had been removed from the amount owed) that would be returned and (other than the occasional 1 penny discrepancy with the odd record caused by rounding errors on monetary datatypes) it works as I would like.

I'm now trying to establish the best way to implement the last little piece of logic.  There are two new columns in the first select statement, InternalCommission and InternalDeduction. These are effectively mutually exclusive (in other words if one contains a value greater than 0 the other will be 0) and they are used to calculate an amount (a percentage of what is currently the TotalToBeReturned) to be either added or deducted.  The goal is to end up with xmlattributes that show to amount paid or deducted in commsion or deduction and the TotalToBeReturned adjusted to reflect these new requirements.

My feeling was that I would need to assign what is now the section that creates the TotalToBeReturned to a temporary value (added to the top of the sql as @tempDeduction and then use that to perform the necessary logic.  However if I try to SET that variable just below where I have added the comment in the query the sql compiler doesn't like it.

So is my reasoning correct, and if so how ought I to be setting that variable and using it to apply the business logic?

Thanks

Comment: A sub-select in the select list aren't allowed to have more than one selected column.

Comment: " two new columns in the first select statement, InternalCommission and InternalDeduction". Is this data in the source XML? Are you actually converting a relational table to XML and back again?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The InternalCommission and IntenalDeduction rates are values in the underlying tables.  They are in effect percentage rates that would be used to multiply the current TotalToBeReturned by in order to hen arrive at a figure to either add to or subtract from that TotalToBeReturned.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's going on in that query but if you add `TotalToBeReturned * (InternalCommission + InternalDeduction) AS '@AnotherColumn',` do you get an error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  What you are suggestion is essentially what I want to do.  However as  TotalToBeReturned is not an actual Column in the underlying tables the compiler throws an error if it's used in the manor you suggest, which is why I thought that I would need to set the tempDeduction variable to the part of the sql that currently creates the TotalToBeReturned and then use that in the sort of logic you suggest.

Comment: Why would you not do this in a scripting language?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that I'm not brilliant with scripting languages there's the little matter of the fact that when a sql query is working efficiently ( and I'm not suggesting that this is as efficient as it could be) it's pretty much untouchable in terms of speed of execution., and in this particular case that is paramount.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone should stumble across this and want to see a resolution. The bottom line was that it is absolutely necessary to refer to the actual underlying table names rather than aliases when execution the logic.  In the end the following worked.

The language has been deliberately set to British English as I want the £ symbol in the resultant xml.  All too often sqlserver ends up with US English as its default.

```
SET LANGUAGE 'British English'
DECLARE @startDate date ,
        @endDate date 




SELECT (SELECT
    ContactId AS '@ContactId',
    VesselOwner AS '@Owner',
    FORMAT(Owed, 'N2') AS '@Owed',
    FORMAT(WeeklyDeductionRate, 'C') AS '@WeeklyDeductionRate',
    FORMAT(FromMinimumReturn, 'C') AS '@FromMinimumReturn',
    FORMAT(DeductionRate, 'P') AS '@DeductionRate',
    FORMAT(TotalDeductions, 'N2') AS '@TotalDeductions',
    Format(TempReturn, 'N2') AS '@TempReturn',
    FORMAT(InternalCommission, 'P') AS '@InternalCommissionRate',
    FORMAT(InternalDeduction, 'P') AS '@InternalDeductionRate',
    FORMAT(InternalCommissionAmount, 'N2') AS '@InternalCommissionAmount',
    FORMAT(InternalDeductionAmount, 'N2') AS '@InternalDeductionAmount',
    FORMAT(TotalToBeReturned, 'N2') AS '@TotalToBeReturned',

    (SELECT DISTINCT
      ld1.ProductId AS '@ProductId',
      FORMAT(AVG(ld1.UnitPrice), 'N2') AS '@Cost',
      FORMAT(SUM(ld1.Quantity), 'N2') AS '@Quantity'

    FROM LandingDetails ld1
    INNER JOIN dbo.LandingHeaders lh1
      ON ld1.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
    WHERE Posted = 0
    AND lh1.VesselOwner = a.VesselOwner
    GROUP BY ld1.ProductId
    FOR xml PATH ('Products'), TYPE)

  FROM (SELECT
    Contacts.ContactId AS ContactId,
    LandingHeaders.VesselOwner AS VesselOwner,
    SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) AS Owed,
    SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate AS WeeklyDeductionRate,
    SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn AS FromMinimumReturn,
    Deductions.DeductionRate,
    Vessels.InternalCommission,
    Vessels.InternalDeduction,
    CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END AS TotalDeductions,


    SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END) AS TempReturn,



    (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END)) * InternalCommission AS InternalCommissionAmount,

    (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END)) * InternalDeduction AS InternalDeductionAmount,


    CASE
      WHEN (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalCommission > 0 THEN (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) + ((SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalCommission)

      ELSE (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) + ((SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalDeduction)
    END AS TotalToBeReturned





  FROM dbo.LandingDetails
  INNER JOIN dbo.LandingHeaders
    ON LandingDetails.LandingId = LandingHeaders.LandingId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Vessels
    ON LandingHeaders.VesselId = Vessels.VesselId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts
    ON Vessels.OwnerId = Contacts.ContactId
  INNER JOIN dbo.SocietyMemberships
    ON Contacts.SocietyId = SocietyMemberships.SocietyId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Deductions
    ON Vessels.DeductionId = Deductions.DeductionId
  WHERE LandingHeaders.Posted = 0
  AND LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  GROUP BY ContactId,
           LandingHeaders.VesselOwner,
           SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate,
           SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn,
           Deductions.DeductionRate,
           Vessels.InternalCommission,
           Vessels.InternalDeduction) a
  ORDER BY ContactId

  FOR xml PATH ('Owner'), TYPE)

FOR xml PATH ('PurchaseOrders'), TYPE
```